# Parsing a HTML table with jsoup to android listview

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-asynctask

I am working on a application which need an html table. After a lot of struggle with finding the right code and solve errors. I came across a error which I can't figure out how to solve it. I figured already out that I need a class which extend Async<>. The only problem is I don't really know how to use Async. the error I got is a fatal exception of Async: "FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1". This not very clear to what to do next or how to solve this. So I hope someone can help me.

The final code is to put the table in an ArrayList and finally to put it in a list view.

This is my code:

[image: code with line numbers]

```
public class Cluka2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Document document = null;
    public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi").get();
           // System.out.println(document);
          //  Log.e("DEBUG", document.toString());
           // Log.v("Debug", document.toString());

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Elements elements = document.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

        for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
        {

            list.add(elements.get(i).text());
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).text());

        }
        System.out.println(list);
        return list.toString();
    }
}
```

This is my error:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
            at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.example.gebruiker.tvnaardentoernooien.Cluka2.doInBackground(Cluka2.java:29)
            at com.example.gebruiker.tvnaardentoernooien.Cluka2.doInBackground(Cluka2.java:12)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
            at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)
            at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: You should show, in the code, where is the line 29.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggle this is my solution for my problem:

This is my Class for connection with the URL and getting the html data

```
   public class ClubkampioenschappenOnderdelenHTMLRequest extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Document document = null;
    public List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    private ListView listView;
    private Context context = null;


    public ClubkampioenschappenOnderdelenHTMLRequest(ArrayList<String> list, Context mContext, ListView ListView) {
        this.list = list;
        context= mContext;
        this.listView = ListView;
    }

    public List<String> getList() {
        return list;
    }

    public void setList(List<String> list) {
        this.list = list;
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {


        try {
            URL url = new URL("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi");
            HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            conn.setRequestMethod("GET");
            conn.setRequestProperty("Accept", "text/html");
            conn.connect();

            InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader((InputStream) conn.getContent());
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(input);
            String line;
            String html = "";

            while((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                html += line;
            }

            document = Jsoup.parse(html);

            Elements elements = document.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

            for (int i = 0; i < elements.size(); i++) {
                list.add(elements.get(i).text());
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return list.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(context, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        listView.setAdapter(arrayAdapter);
    }
}
```

The code in the onCreate method:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_clubkampioenschappen_singleen_dubbel);
        this.setTitle("Onderdelen");

        ConnectivityManager connMgr = (ConnectivityManager)
                getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo networkInfo = connMgr.getActiveNetworkInfo();

        if (networkInfo != null && networkInfo.isConnected()) {

            ListView Onderdelen = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.Onderdelen);
            ClubkampioenschappenOnderdelenHTMLRequest clucka = new ClubkampioenschappenOnderdelenHTMLRequest(list, ClubkampioenschappenSingleenDubbelOnderdelen.this, Onderdelen);
            clucka.execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're getting exception while trying to connect to mentioned site page, then control goes to **catch** block and after that you're accessing not initialized variable **document**, that's why you're getting [NPE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html).

Use **throws** or just runtime wrapping trick to find real cause:

```
} catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aloha,

Put your code that you are asking for inside the try catch statement.  Your variable is out of scope when you try and use it outside of the try catch statement.  The object Elements on line 29 is trying to reference the Document object that was initially declared which is still null. That should get it working for you.

```
    public class Cluka2 extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, String> {

    Document document = null;
    public ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {

        try {
            document = Jsoup.connect("https://tennisnaarden.planmysport.com/portal/page/pmsportal30/TVNaarden/Toernooien/Clubtoernooi").get();
           // System.out.println(document);
           //  Log.e("DEBUG", document.toString());
           // Log.v("Debug", document.toString());
           Elements elements = document.select("#pcnt1383_8158836_1383_4326089_4326089 td:first-child");

           for(int i=0;i<elements.size();i++)
           {

            list.add(elements.get(i).text());
            System.out.println(elements.get(i).text());

           }
           System.out.println(list);
           return list.toString();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
}
```

Your code should look like the above.  Any work that you do in regards to the data retrieved by the document should be handled inside the try catch.  Also since you are adding those elements to the arraylist it needs to be inside the try catch as well.  This should keep your null pointer exception from firing.  As for your AsyncTask just remember the life cycle of the AsyncTask (onPreExecute, doInBackground, postExecute, and onProgressUpdate) and you should be good to go.

Comment: Thanks for the help. The NullPointerException is gone, but only problem is now to retrieve data from the website. I have now a blank page with no data.

Comment: In order to get access to your data you will need to retrieve it in the onPostExecute.  For more details check the [AsyncTask methods on Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)